# Spring boot 2.1.3 update from 2.0.6 causes an BeanDefinitionParsingException for util:map

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have below map bean definition in application context xml and used the map in controller which is causing `BeanDefinitionParsingException` for **spring boot 2.1.3 upgrade**. It works fine in **2.0.6 version**.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Defining "`spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`" in application properties doesn't fix the issue.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {// NOSONAR
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Configuration
    @ImportResource("classpath*:applicationContext.xml")    
    public static class XmlImportingConfiguration {
    }

}

app.properties
#Spring Boot
server.contextPath=/myapp
server.servlet.context-path=/myapp
spring.application.name=myapp
server.tomcat.max-threads=200
server.port=901
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false

logging.level.org.springframework.web: INFO
logging.level.org.springframework: INFO
logging.level.com.wellsfargo: INFO
server.tomcat.accessLogEnabled=false
logging.config=config/log4j2.xml

spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp

applicationContext.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <util:map id="lookup">
            <entry key="60" value="1 hour"></entry>
            <entry key="480" value="8 hours"></entry>
            <entry key="1440" value="24 hours"></entry>
            <entry key="2880" value="2 days"></entry>
        </util:map>
</beans>

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController{
    @Resource(name="lookup")
    private Map<String,String> lookup;

}
```

Error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Invalid bean definition with name 'lookup'
>   defined in null: Cannot register bean definition [Generic bean: class
>   [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
>   for bean 'lookup': There is already [Generic bean: class
>   [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
>   bound.

Comment: where did you define the map and is it included in the configuration

Comment: it's defined in applicationContext.xml

Comment: Can you add your application context xml?

Comment: @skumar I've added a basic example https://github.com/DarrenForsythe/resource-bean-override the only way I can re-create the issue is having two beans named "lookup", which makes me think there is another hiding somewhere with the name lookup - note bean definition is related to the name of the beans not their types, so if theres another called "lookup" definined anywhere else it will error

Comment: @skumar as Darren pointed out there is another lookup defined somewhere else clean your build folders manually it may be because of IDE issue also

Comment: there is no another lookup defined in the xml. if it's defined i would have got the same error in 2.0.6 spring boot.

Comment: @Darren I have updated the applicationcontext xml above

Comment: @skumar is that you entpire application context xml? Can you add any java configurations, your main spring boot application class, and you app properties/yml. Also how are you launching the application?

Comment: @Darren, yes that's entrie application context. i have added the java configuration, spring boot class and app properties. It's launched in cloud PCF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have workaround for this problem. Basically moved the map from applicationContext.xml to application properties and retrieved using @Value like below.

```
app.properties
lookup={'60':'Last 1 hour','480':'Last 8 hours','1440':'Last 24 hours','2880':'Last 2 days'}

ApplicationProperties.java
    @Value("#{${lookup}}")
    private Map<String,String> lookupTimeinterval;
```

Comment: You might also want to consider [@ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what are you looking for but why not to replace XML with Java Config. You should not enable bean overriding as it makes debugging Spring IoC startup problems very, very hard.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public Map<String, String> lookup() {
      return Map.of(
            "60", "1 hour", 
            "480", "8 hour", 
            "1440", "24 hours", 
            "2880", "2 days"
      );
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont want to hardcode the constants in the code. Anyhow I have come up with different solution one mentioned below.

Comment: @skumar perhaps your real life example is more complex but the example constants make no sense, they can be calculated using `Duration` class or simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

you can also if you want to instead of using a "application.properties" file you can use a "yaml" file.

Yaml has support for key values in properties.

application.yaml

```
myVales:
  60: "1 hour" 
  480: "8 hour" 
  1440: "24 hours" 
  2880: "2 days"
```

MyConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyConfig {

    private Map<String, String> myValues;

    //getters

}
```